# Why should we not use Internal libraries and use original library?

Tags: java, guava

I was using Guava Internal libraries in my project:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.HashBasedTable;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.Table;
```

It is suggested me to not use these internal and use original library.

Is there specific reasons of not using internals, i mean any legal concerns?

Comment: You should ask the person who suggested it. We can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal packages are not meant to be used directly by clients of the library.

The developers of the library have no obligation to keep the internal packages backwards compatible, and they may even eliminate some classes of the internal packages in future version, and replace them by others.

If your code relies on internal packages, it has a high risk of breaking when you upgrade to future versions of the library.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with using internal libraries isn't usually around legal restrictions, but about supportability and compatibility.

Internal libraries are designed to be just that - internal, and their authors and maintainers treat them as such in the sense that they may make breaking changes (or even completely remove functionality) without notice. Applications using such libraries could break if you upgrade the library you're using.